# Copy range in excel, find specific text in MSWord document, replace with clipboard image

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, copy-paste

I'm copying a range in excel as an image, and I want to insert it into a word document as replacement for dummy text "Qwerty01". Right now it opens the word document and pastes the image at the top - how can I get it to move the cursor to the dummy text before pasting?

```
Sub automateword()

Dim sheet1 As Object
Dim wdFind As Object

Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")
wordapp.documents.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Word.docx"


wordapp.Visible = True
Set sheet1 = Sheets("Prog General (1)")
Set wdFind = wordapp.Selection.Find

sheet1.Range("D14:N46").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
wdFind.Text = "Qwerty01"
wordapp.Selection.Paste
End Sub
```